# How to input a float as a string of '0' and '1' characters with the bitstring package?

Tags: python, binary, floating-point, bitstring, mpmath

I want to use the packages `bitstring` and `mpmath` (or any other way to guarantee an arbitrarily set output precision and specified rounding mode) to calculate values of `rcp`, `sqrt`, `sin`, `co`s, `ln`, `exp`,... on float inputs given as binary `bitstring`s and get a binary `bitstring` answer.

My go-to for this is MPFR in C, but I want to explore Python's floating point high-precision packages, hoping for easier handling. My first problem is how to reverse the following decimal float to `bitstring` conversion:

```
>>> from bitstring import *
>>> a = BitArray(float=1.2,length=32)
>>> a.bin
'00111111100110011001100110011010'
```

i.e. how to feed `'00111111100110011001100110011010'` to either `bitstring` or `mpmath` in a way that it interprets it as (just over) `1.2` and then feed that to a function such as `sin`, `cos`, or `ln` (turning my answer into a `bitstring` again).

I'm finding it hard to learn about binary **input** from the Python `bitstring`/`mpmath` documentation. It only says about the difficulties of decimal float representation, but not how to bypass these simply inputting exact binary floats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BitArray` takes the `bin` parameter, which initialises it from a binary string representation:

```
>>> from bitstring import *
>>> a = BitArray(float=1.2, length=32)
>>> a.bin
'00111111100110011001100110011010'
>>> b = BitArray(bin=a.bin)
>>> b.float
1.2000000476837158
```

So a general function to do this:

```
def float_from_bitstring(bitstring):
    return BitArray(bin=bitstring).float
```

Answer (score 2):

According to `BitArray` doc string, you can specify `bin` argument:

```
__init__(self, auto=None, length=None, offset=None, **kwargs)
    Either specify an 'auto' initialiser:
    auto -- a string of comma separated tokens, an integer, a file object,
            a bytearray, a boolean iterable or another bitstring.

    Or initialise via **kwargs with one (and only one) of:
    bytes -- raw data as a string, for example read from a binary file.
    bin -- binary string representation, e.g. '0b001010'.   <--------------
    hex -- hexadecimal string representation, e.g. '0x2ef'
    oct -- octal string representation, e.g. '0o777'.
    uint -- an unsigned integer.
    int -- a signed integer.
    float -- a floating point number.
    uintbe -- an unsigned big-endian whole byte integer.
    intbe -- a signed big-endian whole byte integer.
    floatbe - a big-endian floating point number.
    uintle -- an unsigned little-endian whole byte integer.
    intle -- a signed little-endian whole byte integer.
    floatle -- a little-endian floating point number.
    uintne -- an unsigned native-endian whole byte integer.
    intne -- a signed native-endian whole byte integer.
    floatne -- a native-endian floating point number.
    se -- a signed exponential-Golomb code.
    ue -- an unsigned exponential-Golomb code.
    sie -- a signed interleaved exponential-Golomb code.
    uie -- an unsigned interleaved exponential-Golomb code.
    bool -- a boolean (True or False).
    filename -- a file which will be opened in binary read-only mode.

    Other keyword arguments:
    length -- length of the bitstring in bits, if needed and appropriate.
              It must be supplied for all integer and float initialisers.
    offset -- bit offset to the data. These offset bits are
              ignored and this is intended for use when
              initialising using 'bytes' or 'filename'.
```

---

```
>>> a = BitArray(bin='00111111100110011001100110011010')
>>> a.bin
'00111111100110011001100110011010'
```

Use `float` property to get float value:

```
>>> a.float
1.2000000476837158
>>>
```